# is using a socket a good way to check for server is up?

Tags: java, sockets, solr

is using a socket a good way to check for server is up?
like this

```
public boolean hostAvailabilityCheck(String serverAddress, Integer serverPort) {
    try {
        Socket s= new Socket(serverAddress, serverPort);
        s.close();
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

or is this better

```
public boolean isServerAvailable(String serverAddress, Integer serverPort) {
    boolean isAlive = true;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http:/" + serverAddress + serverPort);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.connect();
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        isAlive = false;
    }

    return isAlive;
}
```

Im trying to see if a solr server is up to push data Im not sure which is good! I hope 
 org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response
Class SolrPingResponse does the same thing. Thanks

Comment: Well, if you can connect to the server it's most likely up and running.:)

Answer (score 0):

Opening a socket is only useful if you know a specific service with port that is running on the destination host.

You can also use [`InetAddress.isReachable()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable-int-) which tries multiple methods to test if the host specifiied by InetAddress is reachable. Of course this method is also not a 100% guarantee because it does not have knowledge of custom configured services, but it's a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Accepting a socket connection doesn't necessarily indicate that the server can process a request at that time. Sending a http request is much better way to check the availability of the server. This is the most widely used by load balancers to check the server availability to process a request. In addition to making a http connection, you to need to send a dummy request & confirm that the HTTP sends success status code for it.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the definition of [`new Socket(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket(java.lang.String,%20int)), this could establish a server presence on any arbitrary port (e.g. you may allow sockets from port 22, ssh).  It's just a matter of what all ports you attempt.

The second code does something *very* different!  Instead of merely testing whether the given URL connects to *a server*, it asks whether the given URL connects to *an HTTP server*!  If the URL is not backed by an HTTP server then the connection fails...

...It fails to get an `HttpURLConnection` because there is no HTTP server to create an HTTP connection--not because the server (at this address) cannot accept information from other ports.

Answer (score 0):

The `ping()` method of `SolrJ` does more than just connect to the socket, it also issues an HTTP GET request to `/admin/ping` to see that the container and Solr application is responsive. This allows SolrJ to test that the Solr instance is actually answering queries as well, and not just that the container is still accepting socket connections.

Whether that distinction is important to you is something you'll have to decide for yourself, although I'd suggest to include SolrJ in your test and use the `ping` method to check for connectivity yourself.

In a 3rd party application monitoring solution you'd make the monitoring application make an HTTP GET request to `/admin/ping` for the best results.